# Canvas image scaling, rotating, drawing

Tags: javascript, canvas

For a game project, I'm drawing images using their properties such as fileName, position, scale, rotation.

Here is the part that does the drawing:

```
this.context.save();
this.context.translate(item.position.x, item.position.y);
if (item.rotation > 0) {
    this.context.rotate(item.rotation * (Math.PI / 180));
}
if (item.scale.x !== 1 || item.scale.y !== 1) {
    this.context.scale(item.scale.x, item.scale.y);
}
var width = item.imageSize.width * item.scale.x;
var height = item.imageSize.height * item.scale.y;
this.context.drawImage(this.assets.image[item.fileName], -(width / 2), -(height / 2), width, height);
this.context.restore();
```

(don't mind the strange positioning, it's not important)

This works fine, but there is one thing that I don't understand:

Rotation and scaling can be done in two different ways: first scale and then rotate, or other way around. Logically, one would think that first scale then rotation is correct, but for some reason, it only works correctly if I first rotate then scale.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Wow, funky! I would expect that order wouldn't matter for these sorts of transformations...

Answer (score 2):

Where is your point of origin for your objects? Are the x/y the top left? If so that could be causing the issue.

**[Demo Scaling Then Rotating](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/sekhk/1/)**

```
ctx.translate(box.x, box.y);
ctx.scale(2,2);
ctx.rotate(box.angle);
```

**[Demo Rotating Then Scaling](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/sekhk/2/)**

```
ctx.translate(box.x, box.y);
ctx.rotate(box.angle);
ctx.scale(2,2);
```

If you notice both of those demos work fine regardless of when I perform the scaling and rotating. My point of origins however (where I translate to) are in the center of the boxes.

To answer your question (or attempt to) there is no right or wrong way, you can scale first or rotate first, its really just a matter of preference.

Comment: If you scale x and y equally, then they result the same, but not if you scale the x and y differently... See http://jsfiddle.net/sekhk/3/ and http://jsfiddle.net/sekhk/4/

Comment: @Lukas good point, however I just took that as common sense so I didn't mention it, but that could very well be his issue.

Comment: Arg, cant edit the above comment, meant common knowledge not common sense.. that came off a bit rude.

Answer (score 1):

The "correct way" really depends on what you're trying to do. For you, it seems like rotating and then scaling results in what you expect.

Here is a fiddle that shows the difference between rotating then scaling and scaling then rotating: http://jsfiddle.net/HYbC7/3/

What's unexpected for me is when you scale then rotate. If you `scale(x, y)` where `x` and `y` are not equal, then rotate, then the rotation along the x-axis will be different than the rotation along the y-axis and the resulting grid will be skewed.

Comment: This is due to how canvas works with translating ect. Imagine a rubber square, you can only pull from north and south, so if its not rotated when you pull it, it will just look a bit taller, however if you turn it and then pull it you could be grabbing the sides at an angle which will make it look skewed. Scaling always works from x-y axis so if you rotate first and then scale by an uneven amount you will get the weird skewing.